# Is it possible to get the element id of the object clicked when using onblur for input evaluation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using onblur to validate form inputs, but this forces the user to input something in order to escape a field. That's fine if they intend to stick with it, but it prevents them from just resetting the form if they need to start over or cancel. In theory, I'd want a simple if statement to determine if the input clicked is the reset/cancel button, but I'm not able to tell if the onclick even registers when using onblur--which seems to hold the focus on the last field.

I'll use jQuery if necessary, but I think there should be a simple JS solution for this I can't pull out of my trash compactor of a memory.

Here's the code:

```
function checkRequiredEntry(fieldValue,fieldId,error) {
    var field = fieldId;
    if (fieldValue.length == 0) {
        alert(error);
        field.value = "";
        field.focus();
        error = "";
        return false;
        }
    if (fieldValue.length > 0) {
        if (field.id == "zip" || field.id == "phone") {
            checkNumberFormat(fieldValue,fieldId);
        } 
        if (field.id == "email") {
            checkEmailFormat(fieldValue,fieldId);
        }   
    }
}
```

...and a sample of the html:

```
        <textarea rows="5" cols="61" name="message" id="message" onblur="return checkRequiredEntry(this.value,document.getElementById('message'),'A brief comment or question is required to validate your form submission. Thank you.');" style="padding:0;"></textarea>
```

Comment: use html to display errors (not an alert), then in your reset remove any errors...issue solved

Comment: Don't show an alert then, change the color of the field, or just validate on form submit instead of the onblur event of the textarea

Comment: Use onblur but don't use it on the last mandatory field. Also validate before .submit() when submit is pressed too to prevent sneaky people from getting a good validation and then changing something before submit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the validation check would occur 100 mili after the blur and will check a flag if to run something like:

```
<input ... onblur="validate()">
<button onclick="resetInput()"></button>

var flag = true;

function validate() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (flag) { // do validation or anything}
    }, 100);
}

function resetInput() {
    flag = false;
    //do what you want to do
   setTimeout(function() {
        flag=true;
    }, 200);
}
```